# 3d game graphics: Where to start?

Tags: 3d, blender

So I've been programming for a while and I really want to make my first good-looking 3d game, obviously not AAA quality but a game that looks nice. I have the necessary programming skills, good music theory to add some soundtracks but I suck with 3d modelling on blender. I've tried looking up some blender tutorials on youtube but all they do is bust away on their keyboard doing keyboard shortcuts making it look effortless. Half of the tutorials don't even show the keyboard shortcuts being used and even when the shortucts are shown on other tutorials, they are incredibly hard to keep up with. Does anybody have a recommendation on a tutorial that will teach me to make a nice-looking 3d model whilst explaining every tool used?

Comment: Resource questions are almost universally offtopic on most stackexhange sites, while they sometimes are accepted here this is way too broad topic. Try limiting your scope a bit. Anyway, 3D is better asked elsewhere like blender.se but the question is too broad.even there. In my experience you can not learn 3D by following tutorials, you need to learn to think about the problem at hand. The shortcuts will naturally follow as nobody thinks about shortcuts they think about what they are doing and how they could approach the problem. There is no shortcut, practice, practice, meditate and think.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by thinking about my problem at hand?And what should i add to this question to make it less broader?

Comment: Learning how to do something is not about memorizing what key does what or even all the tools. It is about learning to solve problems in the subfield. You should have a goal in mind. Modeling say a car or a house is wastly different from a plant or a human. Modeling with sculpting tools is different from edge loop modeling. UV mapping is different than surface modeling.

Comment: CGCookie would be one of the better places for blender tutorials. They have a free [intro to blender](https://cgcookie.com/course/blender-basics/) and their older [low poly character modelling](https://cgcookie.com/archive/low-poly-character-creation-blender-unity/) series is now free to download.

Answer (score 0):

Not a tutorial. But some shortcut list:

https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=blender+shortcut+cheat+sheet

But the best way to learn it is doing it over and over and over again.

Offtopic. If the game is going on the right track, try find someone expert on blender to help you.

3D modeling is just one step. Texturing and lighting is another big step.

Answer (score 0):

I've been a part of a team who developed a 3D game as a thesis before and what Rafael said is correct; if you're to publish the game in any platform, you should hire someone who's a professional in the grounds of 3D Modeling, creation of concept arts, texturing and the likes. You'll learn more from them, then eventually you'll be able to grasp the topic yourself.

Comment: I don't know anyone who is a pro in 3d game art :(

Answer (score 0):

It just takes a lot of practice to get used to. these people spend many weeks making these videos and cut the footage into 20 minuets. CGGeek, CGCookie, and all these other you tubers are some good ones to watch. if I remember correctly they show which key the press for each short cut.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/112145)